# Is there a way to get all accounts for pda with one missing seed?

Tags: anchor, rust, pda, javascript, seed

```
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = signer,
        seeds = ["dummySeed".as_bytes(), party.key().as_ref(), member.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        space = DummyStruct::LEN
    )] 
    pub dummy: Account<'info, DummyStruct>,
```

let say we have an account with 2 non-constant seeds. In anchor js library, Can we find all members in party like that ?:

```
allMemberInPartyX = GetAllMembersInParty(partyXPublicKey);
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to manually iterate over all possibilities for the seeds, generate the PDA and then check if the account exists.

Comment: Impossible then.

Comment: Not impossible if you know what the original seeds were